# CASE clause doesn't work on column sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query

this is my query

```
SELECT Name, 
       Salary, 
       ReportsTo, 
       CASE WHEN ReportsTo = NULL THEN 'Manager' ELSE 'Employee' END AS R 
FROM Employees
```

but when I run it, the **R** column shows `Employee` for all the records

and when I try to remove the second conditio `ELSE ...`, the **R** shows `NULL` for all records!!!

what is the problem here??

Comment: Note: the duplicate question is tagged with Postgres but the answer is the same. In SQL, comparing a value to NULL with `= < > <> <= >=` operators does not return TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured it out

> the thing is, It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>.
>
> We will have to use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators instead.
> [w3schools => this is where i found the answer](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp)

you can also look at the original doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)!

i wanted to give this answer, in case this happens for another confused fella

Comment: It actually does not return FALSE either. It returns UNKNOWN. Three-valued logic is weird ;)